# jQuery: filter function finding another element than one I am looking for

Tags: jquery

This seems pretty silly but I truly don't understand how this is not working:

```
var center_id = document.getElementById("school_application_fls_center").value;
var formdata = {center: center_id}; 
$.ajax({
    url: "/application/get_housing_options_for_center",
    type: "POST",
    datatype: 'json',
    data: formdata,
    success: function(response){
      var options = $("#school_application_housing_type"); 
      removeOptions(document.getElementById("school_application_housing_type"));
      $.each(response.housing_options, function(i,item) {
        console.log("in the loop"); 
        options.append($("<option />").val(response.housing_options[i].id).text(response.housing_options[i].name)); 
      });
      options.append($("<option />").val('nil').text('None'));
      $('#school_application_housing_type').filter(function(){return this.value==response.housing}).prop("selected", true);
      console.log(response.housing);
    }
});
```

Currently, my only thought is that the `prop()` function is not chaining how I imagine it is, and is being applied to every item in the `#school_application_housing_type <div>` as opposed only the one in which filter returns true, which, having debugged what is actually in the div, there is a unique item in which filter is true, however the first item of the list for which filter returns false, is being marked as selected.

The output of the `console.log(response.housing);`

is

Homestay Single Room

however in the browser,

Homestay Twin Room

is selected.

Comment: What type of element is "#school_application_housing_type"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably `"#school_application_housing_type"` is a `<select>` element.

If so then `options.filter(...)` is wrong. You want to filter the actual options :

```
options.find("option").filter(function() {
    return this.value == response.housing;
}).attr("selected", true);
```

But it's simpler to set the selected value in the `.each()` loop.

```
$.each(response.housing_options, function(i, item) {
    var opt = $("<option />").val(item.id).text(item.name).appendTo(options);
    if(item.id === response.housing) {
        opt.attr('selected', true);
    }
});
```

Or even simpler :

```
    $.each(response.housing_options, function(i, item) {
        $("<option />").val(item.id).text(item.name).attr('selected', item.id === response.housing).appendTo(options);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing the `value` and `selected` attributes incorrectly within your filter. Try

```
$('#school_application_housing_type div').filter(function () {
    return $(this).attr('value') === response.housing;
}).attr('selected', true);
```

Please note that I also changed your selector. `#school_[...]` is an ID and thus there is only one element to filter. I am certain you want to filter some of its children elements. Since I don't know your DOM, you'll have to adjust the selector accordingly by changing `div` to the correct type.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/us1rtdvd/) as a working example and [the documentation on prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for further information.